# Definition of (fully) saturated porous medium

Tags: porous-media

Let us consider a porous medium and let $\psi$ be a hydraulic head. If $\psi \geq 0$ we say that porous medium is fully saturated, otherwise is unsaturated.

How can I imagine saturated porous medium? I mean, let $\psi = 10$ be a value of fully saturated porous medium (so there can't be more water). If $\psi < 0$ than the porous medium can absorb water. Than water will leaks through and we can obtain state $\psi = 0$, so it is saturated porous medium. I don't get why the value of $\psi$ can ascend to $10$, if for $0 < \psi < 10$ the porous medium is also saturated. So I think I have a bad idea of what is saturated porous medium.